# HTML/CSS making 3 images in line responsive and well designed

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

[image: This is how my 3 images in line look at the moment:]

Im trying to make these images to be displayed nicely inline and change its position/size depending on the screen size. This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="row tryRow white">
  <div class="col-xs-4 portfolio-item leftPic">
    <div class="imgWrap">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="~/img/FMA.png" />
      <p class="imgDescription">
       Some text in here </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 portfolio-item centerPic">      
    <div class="imgWrap">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="~/img/SFK.png" />
      <p class="imgDescription">
          Some text in here
      </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 portfolio-item rightPic">     
    <div class="imgWrap">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="~/img/CTG.png" />
      <p class="imgDescription">
      Some text in here </p>                        
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

These images display some text below them when they are hovered on.

This is CSS of one of the images:

```
.leftPic {
opacity:0.5;
border-radius:4px;
max-width: 33%;
width:auto;
}
```

As you can see I am trying to set the max width to 33% as I have 3 images per line, but the margins are not correct and to be honest there is a large problem with this.

**Problem:** To make them shrink, re-position depending on the browser while keeping the relatively sharp look.

Comment: Wait, based on your code you're using Bootstrap. Why do you need to do this at all? Just use the class col-md-4, then col-xs-12 for smaller devices.

Comment: It shrinks depending on the browser size, the images take seperate lines if the screen is made like mobile phone which is fine, but I can't make it to have the same spaces between pictures, all of the pictures are going to the left side, meaning everything looks kinda messy. You can look at the image at the Original post, as you can see, margin from left corner is different from right after the last picture, "Couple of my projects" is centered and images below are all going to the left side.

Comment: add a plunkr/fiddle  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... I would approach it in a different way setting `background-image` instead of using html `<img>`. As you expect nice responsive behavior and your images are quite small have a look at this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="image image-1">Some text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="image image-2">Some text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="image image-3">Some text</div>
    </div>
</div>

.image {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    // height: control it with media queries
}

.image-1 {
    background-image: url(path/to/image-1.jpg);
}

.image-2 {
    background-image: url(path/to/image-2.jpg);
}

.image-3 {
    background-image: url(path/to/image-3.jpg);
}
```

This approach will also give you more flexibility styling those boxes content.

Answer (score 1):

i tried with this one:

```
.tryRow{  display: inline-block;}
```